# How to save custom settings in settings.default?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to save a `List<CustomClass>` into settings.default. I am able to manipulate the data within it but i doesn't seem to be saving.

I have also tried saving other datatype like strings and that seems to work. `List<CustomClass>` doesn't seem to be saving even though the data is being manipulated.

Saving:

```
        private void FormMain_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.Default.CSVData.Clear();
            foreach (CSVData cd in csvSettings) {
                Settings.Default.CSVData.Add(cd);
            }

            foreach (CSVData cd in Settings.Default.CSVData) {
                MessageBox.Show(cd.path);
            }
            Settings.Default.Save();
            Settings.Default.Reload();
        }
```

Loading:

```
 private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            csvSettings = new List<CSVData>();

            if (Settings.Default.CSVData == null) {
                Settings.Default.CSVData = new List<CSVData>();
            }

            if (Settings.Default.CSVData != null) {
                foreach (CSVData cd in Settings.Default.CSVData) {
                    csvSettings.Add(cd);
                }
            }

            foreach (CSVData cd in Settings.Default.CSVData) {
                MessageBox.Show(cd.path);
            }
        }
```

Settings.settings file:

```
    <Setting Name="CSVData" Type="System.Collections.Generic.List&lt;mp3_Tagger.CSVData&gt;" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
```

If anyone can provide some insight as to why this is not working that would be great.

Comment: My guess would be that the User Settings engine doesn't know how to create the CSV object, which is why it probably works for strings.  Just use a file to do this.

Comment: This seems to be it guess ill just use a file was hoping i didnt have too.

Comment: if `CSVData` is serializable, then it can be saved in the `Settings.Default`. But it will require some manual intervention. Without a [mcve], it's impossible to say for sure whether you could get this to work, never mind what specifically you need to change. But you should look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+save+custom+type+to+settings